# Unable to Import Pandas, Numpy, etc When Using Github Desktop for Accessing Group Repo

Tags: python, github, visual-studio-code, repo, github-desktop

I am using Github Desktop to access a group Github repo, while running the code below on a ipynb file in VS Code. When I run the following code, I am unable to import pandas even though I have it installed. When I comment out pandas, I am unable to import numpy, even though I have had that installed as well. And so on...

Any reason as to why this may be the case? Thank you.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-01bc08e5df4c> in <module>
      1 # Dependences
----> 2 import pandas as pd
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      5 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if modules were installed in Jupyter current used environment.

After selecting python interpreter, open a new integrated Terminal and run `pip show pandas`, then see if the module is in folder `lib/site-packages` under the current environment. If not, please reinstall them.

[image]

Reference: [Using Python Environment in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the image Molly. I had Python 3.6 on the bottom left circle and 3.9 on the top right circle. When I changed the top right to 3.6 to match the bottom left, the code was able to run fine. (And just FYI, my pandas location was already set to .../Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages)

Comment: The reason your code works well is because modules have been installed in Python3.6, also you installed it in python3.7 but that's ok. Glad my answer helped you, and it's appreciated that you [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) it for more people to reach it.